# How can I have vertically fixed div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have vertically but not horizontally fixed div element. Currently, I am using jQuery to update the position `top` every time scroll occurs, but I don't want it seeing moving. I would like it to be fixed without moving. Is there a way to do this?

```
 -----------------
|         |       |
|         |       |
| div A   | div B |
|         |       |
|         |       |
|         |       |
 -----------------
```

Scrolling down

```
 -----------------
| div A   |       |
|         |       |
|         | div B |
|         |       |
|         |       |
|         |       |
 -----------------
```

I would like to be able keep `Div B` vertically fixed while `Div A` scrolls down and up. But when I scroll to the right and left, I wand `Div A` and `Div B` to move.

I noticed that Twitter uses something similar. Once you click on a tweet, the element on the right that display the tweet detail, is veridically fixed. I am not sure how they are doing it. See the second image, when scrolling down the right panel stays fixed.

[image]

Second image:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twitter uses a css property: `position: fixed;` which sure is the best way to go.

This does exactly what it says it does, it fixes the position. By using the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties you can set the exact position of your div.

---

**Edit 13-12-11** (awesome date!)

The property `position: fixed;` can not influence a positioning property over one axis only. This means, that you can not scroll left or right, like you want to.

I highly suggest you should either avoid surpassing the screen width, using percentages for your element's width. You can also just stick to your javascript.

You could however go for the method I suggested at first, but change the left property using a scroll event listener so that when you scroll, the left offset is increased or decreased. Because jQuery's bad-ass cross-browser support I'd go for jQuery. I think you can do practically the same with the prototype library, but I'm not familiar with that library.

jQuery (worked in google chrome):

```
var offset = 400; // left offset of the fixed div (without scrolling)

$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    // b is the fixed div
    $('.b').css({
        'left': offset - $(document).scrollLeft()
    });
});
```

Have a look at the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/etPfV/4/)

You might need to change the `document` object to another object or selector of your choice.

Comment: I used `position: fixed;`. It works most of the time, but the problem is that when you first open the page and if `Div B` is only showing half of it and you want to scroll to the right to see it the whole thing, it won't allow you. It will stay the same position.

Comment: Sam, please provide your html code so we can see what you're trying to do

Answer (score 4):

A whole lot of people want this, but unfortunately pure CSS does not offer a way to accomplish this very simple, very useful task. The only way that I have found is to give the div position:fixed. However, as you have found, this fixes the div on both the x and y axes.

This is a big failing in CSS, in my opinion. We really need something like CSS position:fixed-x and position:fixed-y. The only way I have found to do this is to have a piece of JavaScript code that's entered on a SetInterval( ) timeout (I use .10 second) that repositions the div on the axis that needs to change.

In your case (if I read your question correctly) you'd change the top: of DivB at each SetInterval( ) tick, moving DivB down to the position you want it in the viewport. Easy to do and it works, just a needless pain.

You might ask, and rightly, why you (and I) can't do this manipulation when the scroll event fires. The answer is that the scroll event *doesn't* fire in some versions of IE.

If you can make this depend upon scroll event cross-browserly, that would be a huge advance.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

This is easily done with the correct markup and CSS. You need a container (`div`, `section`, etc.) to contain your two content areas. In the following example, I exploit the way JSFiddle renders the fiddle's content, but the technique is the same outside of JSFiddle.

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jsumners/fQde2/)

First, we need the markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="divA">
        <p>This div will scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="divB">
        <p>This div will not scroll.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, the CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    postition: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#divA {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 300%;  /* So we can see scrolling in action */
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
}

#divB {
    background: #c55;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
}
```

In this example, I take advantage of the fact that JSFiddle will create a view port of limited size. Thus, I can specify all of my sizes in percentages.

Notice that I set the container's position to relative. This is so that I can set the position model of divA and divB to "absolute" and "fixed" such that they will be positioned according to the box generated by "container". This is the key part of solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `position:fixed` as style and set a fixed `width` for `div`. also set `top` and `left` or `right` in pixel.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: OP wanted to know how to keep the right panel "fixed" so if the viewport scrolls it stays on top.

Comment: set style as position:fixed, maybe. and the point. Maybe I am unable to fully understand the question.

Comment: My answer is same as below the answer. I fixed it at my comment before, and now fixed in my answer, but why -1????????????

Comment: You are right @jsumners, but if anyone study position:fixed in google, then he/she must understand this easily, I think.

Comment: The point of this site is to be the result of that Google search. Therefore, your answer should be a complete, easy to follow, answer.