# Positioning a fixed div

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to maintain the scroll position of a fixed div in vertical direction only and not in horizontal direction ?  What i want is to have a fixed div which maintains its position only while scrolling vertically

Comment: @Roi http://jsfiddle.net/rpn5ty17/ i want the "fixed" to maintain the fixed position only in vertical direction

Comment: Don't make us go looking for your code, please inlcude it in your question. A filddle is great **in addition** to code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#scroll').scroll(function() {
   if ( $(this).scrollLeft() > 50 ){
       $(".b").css("position","relative");
    }
    else{
        $(".b").css("position","absolute");
    }
});
```

Comment: add a jquery library thou

Comment: I would like pure css thanks though

Comment: i'm afraid it can't be done in css only dear

Comment: you can refer to this too

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475012/how-can-i-have-vertically-fixed-div-element